# SQL Server view not updated in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I created a SQL Server view and updated the view to select date part only without time, and the view is working correctly in SQL Server, I updated the the model from the database in the project Diagram by click on "Update Model From Database".

After update when I run the project in browser its still reading order date with time, I deleted the SQL Server view from the Model Diagram and added it again, but still when run the project in browser it's reading the date with time.

Do I need to update anything in the Model itself in the Models or how to solve this issue?

This is the view :

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[LAB_RESULTS_CLINIC_VIEW] 
AS 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        [LAB_RESULTS].ORDER_ID  as 'order number',
        labtests.TestId as 'Test Id',
        labtests.TestName as 'Test Name'
       ,NORMAL_RESULT as 'Normal'     
       ,cast(LAB_RESULTS.APPROVED_DATE as date) as 'Report Date'
       ,CASE WHEN coalesce([RESULT_NUMBER],'') <> '' THEN RESULT_NUMBER WHEN coalesce(RESULT_REPORT, '') <> '' THEN RESULT_REPORT END AS Result 
       ,[RESULT_NOTE]   as 'Notes'
     ,TestsRanges.LowerLimit as 'Low Range'
      ,TestsRanges.UpperLimit as 'High Range'
     ,TestsRanges.panic_value as 'Panic'
      ,TestsRanges.text_range as 'Text Range'
       ,machines.machine_name
      ,LAB_RESULTS.CUSTID as 'Customer No'
      ,Customers.CustName as 'Customer Name'
      ,LAB_RESULTS.patient_no as 'Patient No'
      ,Patients.PATIENT_NAME as 'Patient Name'
      ,Patients.PCfileNo as 'Clinic File No'
      ,patientcat.CatName as 'Category'
      ,Patients.Age AS 'AGE'
      ,gender.gendername as 'SEX'
      ,labtests.TestNotes as 'Test Note'
      ,TestsUnits.UnitName as 'UNIT'
      ,LAB_RESULTS.deptid AS 'DEPTID'
      ,cast(Lab_Hematology_Samples.COLLECTION_DATE as date) as 'Collection Date'
      ,cast(Lab_Hematology_Samples.RECEIVING_DATE as date) as 'Receiving Date'
      ,Groups.groupdesc as 'Group Name'
      ,LAB_RESULTS.SERIAL
      ,LAB_RESULTS.GROUPID
      ,LAB_RESULTS.packageid
      ,LAB_RESULTS.EXAMINED_BY
      ,LAB_RESULTS.APPROVED_BY
      ,UPDATED_BY
      ,UPDATED_DATE
      ,Lab_Result_Comments.comments as 'Comments'
      ,Departments.Dept_name as 'department name'


  FROM [dbo].[LAB_RESULTS]
  inner join LabTests on LabTests.testid=LAB_RESULTS.TESTID
  inner join TestsRanges on  LAB_RESULTS.TESTID=TestsRanges.TestId 
  inner join Departments on  LAB_RESULTS.deptid=Departments.Dept_id 
  inner join PatientCat on patientcat.CatId = TestsRanges.CatId
  inner join Customers on Customers.CustId=LAB_RESULTS.CUSTID
  inner join patients on Patients.Patient_No = LAB_RESULTS.patient_no
 inner join machines on lab_results.machine_id = machines.machine_id
  inner join gender on gender.genderid = Patients.Gender
  inner join TestsUnits on TestsUnits.UnitId = LabTests.UnitId
  inner join Lab_Orders on Lab_Orders.ORDER_ID = LAB_RESULTS.ORDER_ID
  left join Lab_Result_Comments on LAB_RESULTS.ORDER_ID = Lab_Result_Comments.ORDER_ID
  inner join Lab_Hematology_Samples on Lab_Hematology_Samples.SAMPLE_ID = LAB_RESULTS.SAMPLE_ID
  inner join Groups on (Groups.groupid = LAB_RESULTS.GROUPID and Groups.Testid = LAB_RESULTS.TESTID )

  where (Lab_Orders.catid = TestsRanges.CatId or PatientCat.CatId =5)
  and  LAB_RESULTS.EXAMINED_DATE is not null 
  and  LAB_RESULTS.APPROVED_DATE is not null
  and  LAB_RESULTS.SAMPLE_STATUS=6
 and  (Patients.Gender = TestsRanges.PatientSex or TestsRanges.PatientSex = 1 )
  AND TestsRanges.machine_id = LAB_RESULTS.machine_id
 -- and LAB_RESULTS.update_count in (select max(update_count) from LAB_RESULTS where SAMPLE_STATUS = 6 and deptid = @deptid and ORDER_ID = @ORDER_ID)
 AND LAB_RESULTS.DEPTID IN (1,2,3,4)

  UNION ALL 

 SELECT DISTINCT [LAB_RESULTS].ORDER_ID  as 'order number'
       ,labtests.TestId as 'Test Id'     
       ,labtests.TestName as 'Test Name'
       ,NORMAL_RESULT as 'Normal'     
       ,cast(APPROVED_DATE as date) as 'Report Date'
       ,CASE WHEN coalesce([RESULT_NUMBER],'') <> '' THEN RESULT_NUMBER WHEN coalesce(RESULT_REPORT, '') <> '' THEN RESULT_REPORT END AS Result 
       ,[RESULT_NOTE]   as 'Notes'
      ,TestsRanges.LowerLimit as 'Low Range'
      ,TestsRanges.UpperLimit as 'High Range'
      ,TestsRanges.panic_value as 'Panic'
      ,TestsRanges.text_range as 'Text Range'
       ,machines.machine_name
      ,LAB_RESULTS.CUSTID as 'Customer No'
      ,Customers.CustName as 'Customer Name'
      ,LAB_RESULTS.patient_no as 'Patient No'
      ,Patients.PATIENT_NAME as 'Patient Name'
      ,Patients.PCfileNo as 'Clinic File No'
      ,patientcat.CatName as 'Category'
      ,Patients.Age AS 'AGE'
      ,gender.gendername as 'SEX'
      ,labtests.TestNotes as 'Test Note'
      ,TestsUnits.UnitName as 'UNIT'
      ,LAB_RESULTS.deptid AS 'DEPTID'
      ,cast(Lab_Hematology_Samples.COLLECTION_DATE as date) as 'Collection Date'
      ,cast(Lab_Hematology_Samples.RECEIVING_DATE as date)as 'Receiving Date'
      ,NULL AS 'Group Name'
      ,LAB_RESULTS.SERIAL
      ,LAB_RESULTS.GROUPID
      ,LAB_RESULTS.packageid
      ,LAB_RESULTS.EXAMINED_BY
      ,LAB_RESULTS.APPROVED_BY
      ,UPDATED_BY
      ,UPDATED_DATE
      ,Lab_Result_Comments.comments as 'Comments'
      ,Departments.Dept_name as 'department name'


  FROM [dbo].[LAB_RESULTS]
  inner join LabTests on LabTests.testid=LAB_RESULTS.TESTID
   inner join TestsRanges on TestsRanges.TestId = LAB_RESULTS.TESTID
   inner join Departments on  LAB_RESULTS.deptid=Departments.Dept_id 
  inner join PatientCat on patientcat.CatId = TestsRanges.CatId
  inner join Customers on Customers.CustId=LAB_RESULTS.CUSTID
  inner join machines on lab_results.machine_id = machines.machine_id
  inner join patients on Patients.Patient_No = LAB_RESULTS.patient_no
  inner join gender on gender.genderid = Patients.Gender
  inner join TestsUnits on TestsUnits.UnitId = LabTests.UnitId
  left join Lab_Result_Comments on LAB_RESULTS.ORDER_ID = Lab_Result_Comments.ORDER_ID
  inner join Lab_Orders on Lab_Orders.ORDER_ID = LAB_RESULTS.ORDER_ID
  inner join Lab_Hematology_Samples on Lab_Hematology_Samples.SAMPLE_ID = LAB_RESULTS.SAMPLE_ID


  where (Lab_Orders.catid = TestsRanges.CatId or PatientCat.CatId =5)
  and  LAB_RESULTS.EXAMINED_DATE is not null 
  and  LAB_RESULTS.APPROVED_DATE is not null
  and  LAB_RESULTS.SAMPLE_STATUS=6
  and  (Patients.Gender = TestsRanges.PatientSex or TestsRanges.PatientSex = 1 )
  and  LAB_RESULTS.GROUPID = 0
 -- and LAB_RESULTS.update_count in (select max(update_count) from LAB_RESULTS where SAMPLE_STATUS = 6 and deptid = @deptid and ORDER_ID = @ORDER_ID)
 -- and LAB_RESULTS.deptid = @deptid
  AND TestsRanges.machine_id = LAB_RESULTS.machine_id
  AND LAB_RESULTS.DEPTID IN (1,2,3,4)
GO
```

this is my date fields updated to select date part only and working in correct SQL SERVER :

```
    cast(APPROVED_DATE as date) as 'Report Date'
    ,cast(Lab_Hematology_Samples.COLLECTION_DATE as date) as 'Collection Date'
   ,cast(Lab_Hematology_Samples.RECEIVING_DATE as date)as 'Receiving Date'
```

This is Model Details:

```
public partial class LAB_RESULTS_CLINIC_VIEW
    {
        public int order_number { get; set; }
        public int Test_Id { get; set; }
        public string Test_Name { get; set; }
        public string Normal { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Report_Date { get; set; }
        public string Result { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public string Low_Range { get; set; }
        public string High_Range { get; set; }
        public string Panic { get; set; }
        public string Text_Range { get; set; }
        public string machine_name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Customer_No { get; set; }
        public string Customer_Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Patient_No { get; set; }
        public string Patient_Name { get; set; }
        public string Clinic_File_No { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> AGE { get; set; }
        public string SEX { get; set; }
        public string Test_Note { get; set; }
        public string UNIT { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DEPTID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Collection_Date { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Receiving_Date { get; set; }
        public string Group_Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> SERIAL { get; set; }
        public int GROUPID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> packageid { get; set; }
        public string EXAMINED_BY { get; set; }
        public string APPROVED_BY { get; set; }
        public string UPDATED_BY { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> UPDATED_DATE { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        public string department_name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is view browser you see collection date , receiving date and report date appeared date+time:

[image]

Comment: While you can have a `DATE` in SQL Server that has **only** the date portion (no time), there is **no equivalent** for this in .NET - the C# datatype `DateTime` will **always** have a time portion - `00:00:00` if the value from the database is a `DATE`, but still. If you don't want this, you need **change the output format** in the grid to show only the date portion

Comment: @marc_s  yes i need only date without time how i will remove it from the view and site ? what to do ?

Comment: In the view, you're all set - `CAST(... AS DATE)` does that. In .NET, as I said - you **cannot** "remove" the time part - it's always there. But your **grid** that you're using should allow you to specify how to render a `DateTime` and should allow a format that shows *only the date* portion of your `DateTime` value. But I have no idea what grid you're using and how to do this in your grid ---> **read the documentation** for your grid!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following line to your model 
first add library for data annotation :

```
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

then add the following line for format the date :

```
   [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

public partial class LAB_RESULTS_CLINIC_VIEW
    {
        public int order_number { get; set; }
        public int Test_Id { get; set; }
        public string Test_Name { get; set; }
        public string Normal { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Report_Date { get; set; }

        public string Result { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public string Low_Range { get; set; }
        public string High_Range { get; set; }
        public string Panic { get; set; }
        public string Text_Range { get; set; }
        public string machine_name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Customer_No { get; set; }
        public string Customer_Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Patient_No { get; set; }
        public string Patient_Name { get; set; }
        public string Clinic_File_No { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> AGE { get; set; }
        public string SEX { get; set; }
        public string Test_Note { get; set; }
        public string UNIT { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DEPTID { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Collection_Date { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Receiving_Date { get; set; }

        public string Group_Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> SERIAL { get; set; }
        public int GROUPID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> packageid { get; set; }
        public string EXAMINED_BY { get; set; }
        public string APPROVED_BY { get; set; }
        public string UPDATED_BY { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> UPDATED_DATE { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        public string department_name { get; set; }
    }
}
```